# Which is good Practice storing a uploaded File in DB or storing it in Filesystem

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql, sql-server-2005

I have a File Uploader in my ASP.NET application Using C#, we can upload any type like images, documents, pdf etc.

I m storing it in the Filesystem and having only the Name of the File in DB. 
My doubt is can we store the entire file, images in DB. State me Which is good practice and why we need to use it.

Either file System Storage or SQL DB Storage.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Almost the same question was asked here. Check the answer:

[Working with images in WCF](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2467774/working-with-images-in-wcf)

It mostly depends on the size of your files. Here's a nice article.

[To BLOB or Not To BLOB](http://research.microsoft.com/apps/pubs/default.aspx?id=64525)

For less than 256kb files storing in DB in VarBinary column is more efficient.

We store our files in MS SQL Server in a VarBinary column with 256kb restriction and it works fine.

Hope it helps. Good Luck!

Answer (score 2):

This is <strike>argumentative</strike> subjective, but I would say that storing files on the files system is better. That's what file systems are designed for and SQL Server 2008 has a [new file type](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc949109.aspx) that allows you to do this automatically and even use transactions.

Comment: I think subjective rather than argumentative

Answer (score 0):

Depends on:

1. How big the file is, though big blobs can be handled efficiently in RDBMs
2. Is it read or write heavy?
3. How many concurrent requests for that resource
4. Are you using any other caching mechanisms
5. Do you have a SAN available, or a clustered filesystem

In short, without specifics, best practice is hard to give. Just depends on your constraints and requirements like any task.

Comment: hey Bell, i m not much familar with SQL but the file size would not be more than  1 or 2MB for a record. The Concurrent request would not be much. Give Me most common used system.

Answer (score 0):

In addition to the other answers that seems to concentrate on performance I'd also add access as another issue. If the files contains confidential data or access to the files needs to be audited, it is can sometimes be easier to manage this if the files are stored in a DB.

Comment: @ho - Yes but storing a secret path in the DB and having an intermediate script deliver the payload can give you the same 'barrier'

Comment: Not really, as you dont really have a trace whether it was changed. Then also another issue is backup / restore. easier in one place.