# Shoud I store my PDFs for download in Frontend or Backend?

Tags: reactjs, pdf, frontend, backend

I create a homepage  with a download center for PDFs.
Is it better to store it in the frontend or in the backend or is this irrelevant ?

Edit for the comment:

-> it will be a website planned for 3.000 user per month

-> not sure what PWA is, but the page gets a responsive design for computer and smartphones

-> the PDFs should be accessible for everyone, like a manual or a sample of contracts

Comment: Given the context you provide, answers to your question may be opinion-based. Could you please add more information to it, wether that is a toy project or a professional one, a PWA, wether the PDFs should at some point be accessible to other users or are just for the individual using the application...

Comment: i did a edit :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given that information needs to be accessible to different users I would say that **it has to be stored in a server and managed by the backend**, which would be equivalent to saying "It should be in the backend" on your own terms. This is the simple answer, but as far as I can see, two questions arise here:

**How to store the data**

Once established that the data resides on the backend part of the system you would have to choose between **having the PDFs stored in the file system and the backend serving files statically** or **having the PDFs stored as BLOBS in the database**. Both have their advantages and drawbacks, [more information here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5251101/store-pdf-in-sql-or-path).

**Should it be accessible offline**

If the user needs to access some information while offline then you would have to store those PDFs on his device. Another reason to do that would be if the PDFs are very large and they don't change that often but they could be fetched by an user multiple times in a day and you don't want to have the backend busy serving the same file everytime.

Comment: @KJ you could not cache the viewed PDFs and have them requested everytime, even though they might be the same document. Or you could have them cached, especially those authored by the user, on the first view (or based on a more performance based metric) and serve them from the local storage or local database. That is on a purely online application, if it is a PWA, IMO, there's no discussion about it.

Comment: @KJ I'm not going to discuss that as what you are saying sounds about right. The point of the question is focused in a ReactJS application, as stated by the tags, so I would say the frontend is a web application... Necessarily a database would have to keep track of the PDF files stored in the system for any user to look them up, the database could also keep a record of the last edited property of the PDF so the client could check before serving the local file and if the last edited properties match do not download the file, and if they don't update the client's resources. Thus reducing traffic